# How to change folder for "Ignore" emails in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use the "ignore" function for a *lot* of emails in Outlook, due to some out of whack business processes that include me on a lot of irrelevant emails.

However, this is becoming a problem as it is really clogging up my "Deleted Items" folder which I need to show up in searches sometimes when I'm looking for previous emails to reference.

I'd like to change the folder that "Ignore" uses to a custom one that I can exclude from searches.  The environment I work in is pretty locked down, and so I don't have access to the registry and can't install any software or things like that for any potential solutions.

I've had a couple thoughts of my own, but don't have the skills to implement them and so thought I'd reach out and see what others have done and what is even possible:

- Change the built in function behind the Outlook "Ignore" via some kind of configuration or customization.
- Create a custom Outlook function mirroring "Ignore" but uses my custom folder.
- Add some kind of functionality to tag/category "Ignored" email threads so that I can exclude them via a filter in a custom search.

Comment: Issue #1: Messages ONLY go in Deleted Items when you're absolutely certain you no longer need them. They should not need to come back up on searches. There is no compelling reason why you should expect or need anything in Deleted Items even again, except if you placed something there by accident. I'm an IT pro and you may be surprised to learn the number of times I've found people using Deleted Items as some sort of storage folder, and they have never had a good reason.

Comment: Issue #2: Outlook is a closed source program. You cannot really re-write its underlying logic. However, Outlook also has a fully-fledged macro system using the same language that Excel uses, and you can make Outlook behave in truly wondrous ways using Macros. But going back to point 1: If you don't need to see those messages, the Deleted Items folder is EXACTLY where they should go. What you need to consider instead is what you're placing those files you may need to retrieve in the Deleted Items folder alongside those you actually don't want.

Comment: @music2myear:  thanks for the lecture, but I'm looking for a solution rather than a load of hot air on design and usage principles.  How I intend to use a particular program is not the issue here, and has zero bearing on addressing the topic.  And telling me it has a truly wondrous macro system is not helpful either, as I am still looking for a solution - not advice on a new career path as an Office macro developer.